# How to change the distance calculation between two nodes in an Accord.Collections KDTree?

Tags: c#, coordinates, large-data, kdtree, accord.net

I have a KDTree that contains about 5 million coordinates. When I search for the closest point to a query point, I want the distance to be calculated using `GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo()` or something similiar.

How can I change the distance function in the KDTree so that the distance between two coordinates (earth curvature) is calculated correctly?